# Spring cache for specific values @Cacheable annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, caching, spring-cache

I want to cache a result of a method only when the attribute of the result contains specific values. For example

```
Class APIOutput(code: Int, message: String)
```

```
sealed class Response<out T : Any> : Serializable {
    data class Success<out T : Any>(val data: T) : Response<T>()
    data class Error(val errorText: String, val errorCode: Int) : Response<Nothing>()
}
```

```
@Cacheable(
        key = "api-key",
        unless = "do something here"
    )
fun doApicall(uniqueId: Long): Response<APIOutput> {
        //make API call
        val output = callAPI(uniqueId)
        return Response.Success(output)
}
```

In the above method, I want to cache the response only when Response.Success.data.code == (long list of codes).
Please note, in the previous line **data** is nothing but APIOutput object. How could I achieve it using unless or any other approach. I was thinking of writing a function that takes a *doApicall* method result as input and would return true or false and call that method it as unless="call a method". But I'm not sure how to do it. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Yatharth and John! Below is the condition that worked for me. **resultcodes** in the below expression is a list

```
@Cacheable(
            key = "api-key",
            unless = "!(#result instanceof T(com.abc.Response\$Success)) 
            or (#result instanceof T(com.abc.Response\$Success) 
            and !(T(com.abc.APIStatus).resultCodes.contains(#result.data.code)))"
)
fun doApicall(uniqueId: Long): Response<APIOutput> {
    //make API call
    val output = callAPI(uniqueId)
    return Response.Success(output)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can specify an expression to be evaluated in `unless` using [SpEL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.10.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html). The returned value is available as `result` so you can do something like -

```
@Cacheable(
        key = "api-key",
        unless = "#result!=null or #result.success.data.code!=200"
    )
fun doApicall(uniqueId: Long): Response<APIOutput> {
        //make API call
        val output = callAPI(uniqueId)
        return Response.Success(output)
}
```

You can even use Regex in SpEL and can create custom Expression parsers if the existing functionality is not enough for your usecase.

Comment: **Yatharth** is correct!  You can read more about _Spring's_ "conditional caching" here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-condition.